# Reporting, figures: good practice to cut y-axes or not?

Tags: data-visualization, reporting

Figure 1 is easier for identifying the difference. However, sometimes the practice of cutting y-axes is not recommended. Which one to report?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you do the cutting? Sometimes clipping the axes removes observations. Or, do you simply want to *zoom in*?

Comment: The question is quite broad, and a little tangled, but the specific advice here is no more than, and no less than, to show zero if you think it would help the reader or your purpose -- ideally the two considerations should lead to the same decision.